# What is the most efficient way of computing $A^{-1}Bc$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

How to obtain the minimum complexity when computing $A^{-1}Bc$? Suppose $A$ and $B$ are $n\times n$ matrices, $A$ is nonsingular and $c$ is an $n$-vector.

Answer (score 3):

A possible approach : First compute $d=Bc$, then use an efficient algorithm to solve $Ax = d$, like [the LU decomposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LU_decomposition).

Comment: How is $LU$-decomposition more efficient than the usual Gaussian elimination? (Or maybe it is just another name for the same algorithm?)

Comment: LU decomposition is about the same as Gaussian elimination, but you can keep the decomposition to solve the system for multiple c. You can also use an efficient matrix multiplication algorithm to push the complexity a little under $n^3$. But if A is not sparse and you need "exact" result, I'm not sure you can do much better than that

Comment: Is QR decomposition better than LU decomposition for this computation?

Comment: I'm not sure, LU is a little bit faster, but less stable numericaly, so it depend of what is exactly your problem.

Comment: @Tsing, in a sense, QR decomposition is more stable (since only one triangular factor is involved), but we use LU decomposition because it is faster and [failures are surprisingly rare](http://dx.doi.org/10.1137/0611023).